# Аліса та Алісія - одне ім'я?

Tags: вживання-слів, власні-назви

Сьогодні почула гукали дитину *Алісія*, коли перепитала, як звати - сказали *Аліса*.

***Виникло питання чи справді це одне і те ж ім'я? Чи можемо вживати як взаємозамінні імена?***

В словнику-довіднику [Власні імена людей](http://slovopedia.org.ua/54/53392/363697.html) є лише Аліса.

> ***Аліса*** запозичене: *фр. Alice*; можливо, від. *гр. aletheia* —істина: можливо, скороч. варіант імені К а л і с т а. 
>   *Алісонька, Алісочка, Аліска, Ала, Аля.*

[Скорочені та пестливі форми імені Аліса](http://privitay.com.ua/znach.php?dat=823) (не зовсім надійне джерело)

> Лисиця, Лисонька, Лісочка, Аля, Алечко, Аленько, Ала, Алочка,
>   Алісочка, Алісонька.

Ім'я Алісія знайшла в Вікіпедії [статтю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) російською мовою.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Коротко

Якщо говорити про загал і грубо, то — **так**.

*Однак* якщо вдати ся в тонкощї і волосник імени знає про це, то не все так просто, бо саме імє *Алісія* може походити від:

- згаданого *aletheia* як *правда*,
- загальноприйнятного *Adalheidis*,
- і раптового *Alexis*.

## Adalheidis

Більшість джерел, особливо чужоземних, згадують як похідного від цего.

Якщо це *Аліса* як в [*Аліса в Дивокраї*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B0_%D1%83_%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97), то тут така етімолоґія:

> [**Alice**](//etymonline.com/word/Alice#etymonline_v_8149)
>
> fem. proper name, from Old French *Aliz*, from Old High German *Adalhaid*, literally "nobility, of noble kind" (see [*Adelaide*](//etymonline.com/word/Adelaide)). Among the top 20 most popular names for girls born in the U.S. c. 1880-1920. "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland," published in 1865, was written for [Alice Pleasance Liddell](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB) (1852-1934).

> [**Adelaide**](//etymonline.com/word/Adelaide)
>
> fem. proper name, from French *Adélaide*, from a Germanic source similar to Old High German *Adalhaid*, from *adal* "noble family" (see *atheling*) + German *heit* "state, rank," which is related to Old English *-had* "person, degree, state, nature" (see [*-hood*](//etymonline.com/word/-hood)). The first element of it affixed to French fem. ending *-ine* gave [*Adeline*](//etymonline.com/word/Adeline).

> [**atheling**](//etymonline.com/word/atheling)
>
> "member of a noble family," Old English *æðling*, from *æðel* "noble family, race, ancestry; nobility, honor," related to Old English *æðele* "noble," from Proto-Germanic **athala-* (cognates: Old Frisian *edila* "(great-)grandfather," Old Saxon *athali* "noble descent, property," Old High German *adal* "noble family"), which is perhaps from PIE **at-al-* "race, family," from **at(i)-* "over, beyond, super" + **al-* "to nourish." With suffix *-ing* "belonging to." A common Germanic word, cognates include Old Saxon *ediling*, Old Frisian *etheling*, Old High German *adaling*.

Тобто походе від ± поняття *шляхетність*. І в такому разї *Alicia* просто [латінізоване](//behindthename.com/name/alicia) *Alice*.

Ций корїнь досить плодовитий, бо з нього маємо дещо знаймі нам імена як *Ада* i *Аліна*. Доречи, до другого згаданий довідник *Власні імена людей* наводить таке:

> [**АЛІНА**](http://slovopedia.org.ua/54/53392/363696.html)
>
> запозичене: нім. Alina, Aline; можливо, виникло через скороч. імен *Ангеліна*, *Аделіна*. *Алінка*, *Алиюнька*, *Алиючка*, *Ала*, *Аля*; *Ліна*.

Здогадати ся можна хиба що за повним іменем *Аделіна* або за скороченими *Ала* і *Аля*, що має і *Аліса*.

Цю думку також припускає [Jan Grzenia](//pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Grzenia) в книзї [*Nasze imiona*](//pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicja):

> *Alicja* może pochodzić od starogermańskiego imienia *Adalheidis*, które skracało się do *Alis*.

## Aletheia

Етімолоґія слова.

> [**aletheia**](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BB%CE%AE%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek)
>
> From *ἀληθής* (*alēthḗs*, “true”) +‎ *-ιᾰ* (*-ia*, abstract noun suffix), from *ἀ-* (*a-*, “not”) and *λήθω* (*lḗthō*, “I escape notice, I am hidden”) — whence English *lethargy* (“sluggishness”) — ultimately from Proto-Indo-European **leh₂-* (“to hide”).

Тобто нічим не збіжне з попереднїм. Згадується і в припущеннях *Nasze imiona*:

> Według innej koncepcji imię *Alicja* pochodzi od greckiego słowa aletheia - prawda, które w średniowiecznej łacinie przyjmowało formę: *Alitia*, *Alicia*.

## Alexis

Найменш популярна думка, бо поки зустрїв в припущеннях *Nasze imiona*:

> Może pochodzić od włoskiej, żeńskiej formy imienia *Aleksy* — *Alessis*, imię to przyjmowało w języku niemieckim i angielskim formę *Alexia*.

Де італійська є посередницею: [*Alessia*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Alessia).

Тобто від корня що і в *Олександер*, отже по сутї наше [*Олеся*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F), анґлійське *Alexia* ітд, що зазвичай не дуже парні до *Аліса*. Тому це не дуже додає вагу або стосується лише в окремих випадках.

## Окремо

Також цїлком можливе злиття перших двох випадків, якщо другий випадок має місце бути. Вплив одного імени на другого — відомий випадок і для української, наприклад зміна **н** → **м** в *Микита* і в похідних словах зазвичай пояснюється таким чином:

> <sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>
>
> [**МИКО́ЛА**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0#12123) (чоловіче ім’я)
>
> Початкове **м** замість **н** у східнослов’янських і польській мовах пояснюється як результат впливу імені *Михаилъ*;

Answer (score -1):

Вже навіть у наведеній вами статті із російської Вікіпедії бачимо, що "**Алісія - це іспанська форма імені Аліса**". А також Аліс ще називають Елісами (див. англійську транскрипцію імені), Лола тощо. Однак, усе це одне ім'я. І на тій же Вікіпедії (тепер українській, яку ви також використали для свого питання) серед інших форм імені Аліса бачимо - Алісія.

Comment: стаття Вікіпедії не переконала мене, що це одне і те ж ім'я. Могли б Ви надати ще якісь джерела підтведження Вашої відповіді.

Comment: погоджуюсь, додаткові джерела не завадили б.